# Equal height of child divs in Bootstrap columns - Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, height

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7q4xjs25/7/)

Basically, the goal is to have side-by-side columns with dynamically-generated content, and have the divs inside the columns be the same height as the div with the longest content.  The important thing is not only that the Bootstrap columns be the same height, but their *child divs* also be the same height.

After cobbling together answers from several different questions, I finally managed to get this to work by using a combination of `table-cell` and setting the height of everything to 100%:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .row {
        display: table-row;
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    [class*="col-"]{
        float: none;
        display: table-cell;
        background-color: red;  /* Color set just to confirm column heights */
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
}

.papers {
    color: #181818;
    border: #ccc solid 1px;
    background-color: #fffaec;
    box-shadow: 
        4px 4px 0 #fffaec,
        5px 5px 0 #ccc,
        9px 9px 0 #fffaec,
        10px 10px 0 #ccc,
        14px 14px 0 #fffaec;
    padding: 0px 30px;    
    text-align: left;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.papers:hover {
    background-color: #e9e5d9;
    box-shadow:
        4px 4px 0 #e9e5d9,
        5px 5px 0 #ccc,
        9px 9px 0 #e9e5d9,
        10px 10px 0 #ccc,
        14px 14px 0 #e9e5d9; 
}
```

Or, so I thought: it works in Firefox (my dev environment), but not Chrome or Safari.  Why?

I need this to work while preserving Bootstrap's stackable grid effects, and in the least hackish way possible.  I'd like to do this with pure CSS if possible.

I've read the other questions on this topic, but most of them are outdated, or only seem to work for controlling the height of the columns themselves.

Edit: @Blake's solution via directly styling the columns: http://jsfiddle.net/7q4xjs25/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element that displays as a `table-row` expects it's parent to behave as a `table`. In-fact, having the parent element set to `display: table;` is what will enable this context for it's children. You don't actually need a `table-row` element, so you can just change your declaration to :

```
.row {
    display: table;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This should cause the elements to behave as you expected!

As an update to address your comment about heights, you can actually remove all of the `height: 100%` and `min-height: 100%` rules.. if they are not present, the `table-cell` elements will all share the height of the tallest content.

However, some of your other styles do seem to rely on these rules, so you may need to do a bit of tweaking. While the column elements will now be sized by content, the `.papers` elements within them will not be (because their parent no longer has a set height that it can fill).. and since these elements are the ones that are visually styled it will look like you've lost the benefits of the previous `display: table` change. To get around this, you will want to make sure that the visually styled elements are the ones that have `display: table-cell` on them. This could mean moving the class of `papers` up onto the column elements, and then working from there to get your spacing back, or you could approach it differently still.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome, that did it!  But, now having everything set to a height of 100% makes the columns the height of the browser window, rather than just tall enough to fit the longest content.  Any idea how I could fix that?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've updated my answer to touch on that issue, hopefully that gives you what you need.. let me know if you have further questions!

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Yeah I had tried applying styles to the columns directly, but then I couldn't get the space between them that I needed without doing something hackish like `col-offset`.

Comment: I took a stab at those tweaks myself: http://jsfiddle.net/7q4xjs25/11/ I took advantage of the fact that we are now in a table context, and used `border-spacing` to get that space around the papers. One little stumbling point I noticed as well is that bootstraps `.row` styles add in `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements which are styled as `display: table;` as well... This will cause some excess spaces, so you may want to just set those to `display: none`. Cheers!

Comment: Ahh, nifty!  Thanks - applying the styles directly to the columns makes things a lot simpler.