# Bootstrap 3 Columns with Equal Height Child Divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.2 to create two columns. Each column has a heading, a bordered div with text of an unknown length, and an image. I need the bordered divs with text to be the same height, but only when the columns are side by side. If the window is narrow enough for the columns to be stacked, they should not be the same height. How can I achieve this?

I realize I could use JavaScript to set the shortest div's height to be the same as the tallest div's height, but the problem with this method is that when the user decreases the width of their browser window, the text overflows outside of the div.

Here is my code ([jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vj3kungb/embedded/result/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            .equal {
                border: 3px solid #333;
                padding: 8px;
            }

            img {
                display: block;
                margin: 20px auto 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1>Foo</h1>

                    <div class="equal">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. His similes sunt omnes, qui virtuti student levantur vitiis, levantur erroribus, nisi forte censes Ti. Pisone in eo gymnasio, quod Ptolomaeum vocatur, unaque nobiscum Q. Eamne rationem igitur sequere, qua tecum ipse et cum tuis utare, profiteri et in medium proferre non audeas? Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Ex ea difficultate illae fallaciloquae, ut ait Accius, malitiae natae sunt. Est, ut dicis, inquit; Id enim ille summum bonum eu)qumi/an et saepe a)qambi/an appellat, id est animum terrore liberum. An est aliquid, quod te sua sponte delectet?</p>
                    </div>

                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1>Bar</h1>

                    <div class="equal">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Tum Torquatus: Prorsus, inquit, assentior; Quid, quod res alia tota est? Maximus dolor, inquit, brevis est. Nihilo beatiorem esse Metellum quam Regulum. Honesta oratio, Socratica, Platonis etiam. Duo Reges: constructio interrete.</p>
                    </div>

                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27611302/937084), but I think it's actually different.

Comment: What's the lowest version of IE you have to support?

Answer (score 1):

```
var equal1 = $(".equal1").height();

var equal2 = $(".equal2").height();

if(equal1 < equal2 ){
    $(".equal1").height($(".equal2").height());
} else {
    $(".equal2").height($(".equal1").height());
}

Please, see this
```

[Demo result](https://jsfiddle.net/jakiir/zq8jrysu/9/embedded/result/)

or

[Demo with code.](https://jsfiddle.net/jakiir/zq8jrysu/9/)

Comment: I don't think JavaScript is a great approach for this because if a user resizes their window, the layout could break. As an example, I modified your jsFiddle to add some more text to the left column ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/zq8jrysu/10/embedded/result/)). Try opening the link in a maximized window and then make the window more narrow and you will see the text overflow outside of the div. I also might be changing `col-md-6` to `col-sm-6`, in which case a tablet user could break the layout just by rotating their tablet. I don't know if flexbox could help in this scenario or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just with pure CSS you can solve it with [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

You can add another class to your row class and then apply the styles on that class.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row row-eq-height">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            ...
```

In the css add:

```
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;         /*to enable responsiveness*/
}

.row-eq-height > [class*="col-"] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

You can check a demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gugol/vzwju1hr/).

Comment: I looked at your demo and the two "Lorem ipsum" `div`s are not the same height.

Comment: They are visually.

Comment: The two `div.col-xs-6`s are equal height, but not the two `div.equal`s.

Comment: Yes, because of this `.row-eq-height > [class*="col-"]`. It works as expected to me.

Answer (score 0):

Updated !

[Try DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yf0sn36p/1/light/)

Using JavaScript

```
$(".equal2").height($(".equal1").height());
```

Do Read http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61

Comment: Thank you, but the length of the text isn't known, so whatever height I specify as the `min-height` could end up making the div too tall or not tall enough. Sorry, I should have mentioned that the length of the text isn't known. I edited the question just now.